# Largest invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries, denote by $inv(A)$ the dimension of a largest dimensional non-trivial invariant subspace of $A$. What is:
$$\inf\{inv(A): A\in\mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{C})\}$$

Comment: What is $\operatorname {inv} A$ when $A$ is a non-trivial plane rotation? In that case, note, the only invariant spaces are $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb R^2$: both trivial.  That would yield $-\infty$ for the real plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $n-1$. Note that due to the structure of the root spaces, you have nontrivial invariant subspaces of any dimension up to $n-1$. In fact $inv(A)$ is itself $n-1$ for any matrix $A$, for the same reason.

*Changed:* replaced "of any (complex) dimension" by "of any dimension" (I was assuming that the OP wanted $A$ to have only real entries).

Comment: I missed the complex coefficient assumption which you are making.

Comment: I presume that $A$ has real entries. So the root spaces may be outside $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: What if $A$ has complex entries. I don't think I follow.

Comment: A matrix with real entries may have nonreal eigenvalues. In that case the corresponding invariant subspaces are not contained in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $\pm i$, the corresponding invariant spaces are $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: The question seems to be about nontrivial invariant subspaces...

Comment: $A$ has complex entries, not necessary real entries. So you are saying that any such matrix will have an invariant hyper-plane? .

Comment: In that case, simply erase "(complex)" from my answer and all is fine. Indeed, any such matrix will have an invariant hyperplace, of ANY dimension. Simply use the Jordan canonical form.